# Issue with text-input field while using css {direction:rtl}

Tags: javascript, html, css, textfield, input-field

I am making a calculator for binary numbers. I use the text input field to enter binary numbers and operator, in which I enter values using virtual buttons and I want that when the input field will become overflow then It should look like [...10100101010] therefore I have used CSS {direction: rtl; text-overflow: ellipsis;} but I have arisen a problem that is when I input any operator by clicking buttons that uses the same function which is used by other buttons, the operator looks like [     +10001] rather than like [     10001+].
Help me to fix the above problem. My code is given below.

```html
<html>
<title>Binary Calculator</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input id="input" style="direction:rtl; text-overflow:ellipsis;" type="text" >
<br>
<br>
<input  onclick="enter('0')" value="0" type="button">
<input onclick="enter('1')" value="1" type="button">
<input onclick="enter('+')" value="+" type="button">
<input onclick="convert()" value="Convert" type="button">
<script>
function enter(n_val){
document.getElementById("input").value += n_val
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like symbols don't play very well with the RTL property and they can display unexpectedly.
I found that placing `&#x200E;` or `&lrm;` before and after the `+` like so, works to achieve what you wanted:
Your code:

`<input onclick="enter('+')" value="+" type="button">`

Solution:

`<input onclick="enter('&#x200E;+&#x200E;')" value="+" type="button">`

I don't fully understand it myself so see [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H34.html) for a better explanation.

For bidirectional languages (and possibly uses with symbols/letters too), where your html code allows you to wrap text in elements, you can use  to wrap different-directional text to get it to display how you want.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/bdi) for further info.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I wanted to add some decimal calculations in my code. If I am using your &lrm; and take input.value and store it in any variable let x then use eval(x) function to solve it then eval() is not working such as if I entered 1+2 in that input field and store this expression in a variable x and use eval(x) then it's not solving that expression. But before using &lrm eval() function was working well. Help me how can I fix that newly emerged problem after using &lrm;.

Comment: Sorry buddy, my guess is as good as yours there! I don't know any javascript at all, and am a beginner at html. Good luck!